# Can't access the values on a dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I'm programming an evolutive algorithm which, I'm having trouble trying to access the data I store in a dynamic matrix like this:

//tam_pob = size of population, is a constant value
//n is a parameter received from user

```
float (* x)[tam_pob] = new (nothrow) float [n][tam_pob];
float(* factor)[tam_pob] = new (nothrow) float [n][tam_pob];


    if(x== 0 || factor == 0)
            cout<<"ERROR...";
    else{

            srand( time( NULL ) );

        for(int j=0;j<tam_pob;j++) // individuos

           for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){ //cromosomas

              //filling the matrix

              x[i][j]=(double) pow(-1.0,(rand()%4))*rand()+rand()/100000.0;
              factor[i][j]=(double) pow(-1.0,(rand()%4))*rand()+rand()/100000.0;


            }
```

but when I try to print the values, the program print something very different that is supposed to be stored in the matrix.
Also it crashes when the value of the size of population is bigger than 250 aprox., I'm supposed to do it with even bigger size of population like 1k,10k and 100k. any ideas?

Comment: `vector<vector<float>> matrix(y_size, vector<float>(x_size)); matrix[y][x] = ...`

Comment: Check that `n` and `tam` are the same. You are not telling what's going on between filling and printing, so no word as to what else could have went wrong. Last but not least, don't use legacy C arrays in C++. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: What's `tam`? You're in trouble if it's larger than `n`.

Comment: tam is same size as n, Neil Kirk i'm going to try that

Comment: How i can declare just the matrix without initiliaze the size values on the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Its probably because of your array initialization. To initialize double array in C++ is a little bit complicated especially if you are initialization it with undetermine variable such as N. I suggest you initialize it like this:

  float ** x = new float *[n];
  float **factor = new float *[n];

  for(int i=0; i < n; i++){

  x[i] = new float[tam_pob];

  factor[i] = new float[tam_pob];
  }
- Since N and tam_pob are undetermined you can pass them as you test it, that way you do not incur an ArrayOutOfBound Exception or null pointer references.
- Something else you need to worry about is that your matrix have got different size represented by N and Tam_pob variables. If this two variables have different sizes you need to loop through each bucket separately so your for loop should use N and tam_pob to check array bound.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to create a two dimensional array, why not use the STL's vector or array class, where each element is also an array/vector, as Neil says?

If you want to avoid using the STL, this is what you probably need:

```
float** x = new float*[n];
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    x[i] = new float[tam_pob];
```

x is then an array of n x tam_pob floats, of which you can index such as `x[3][4]` for example.

As an aside, the parentheses around `x` and `factor` make it look like you are trying to declare function pointers.

If you are going to be writing a lot of code that uses matrices, then a specialised library might make life easier for you, such as http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main () {
  using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
  matrix<double> m (3, 3);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1 (); ++ i)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2 (); ++ j)
      m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```